# How to get only numbers from a character string "../playerB/1600124.html" in R?

Tags: r, readr

I've got the following warning when I tried to use `readr::parse_number()` to get numbers from the character string.
How can I suppress this warning and simply get the number from the string?

```
> parse_number("../playerB/1600124.html")
Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row col expected                  actual
  1  -- a number ../playerB/1600124.html

[1] NA
attr(,"problems")
# A tibble: 1 × 4
    row   col expected actual                 
  <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>                  
1     1    NA a number ../playerB/1600124.html
```

Comment: could you use `str_extract()`,  `str_extract("../playerB/1600124.html", "\\d+")`. You might need to tweak the pattern in case there were numbers in the path.

Comment: @George Thank you. It worked without any issues. Then, why did parse_number() not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"."` is considered as a decimal separator according to your locale. Change it to something else and you should get your expected output.

```
library(readr)

parse_number("../playerB/1600124.html", locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
#[1] 1600124
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `str_match_all` with the pattern `[0-9]+` to get all numbers in your string like this:

```r
string <- c("../playerB/1600124.html")
library(stringr)
string %>% 
  str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% 
  unlist 
#> [1] "1600124"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>